# Dart Lang: Avoid marking all functions with async

Tags: asynchronous, dart, dart-async

Dart newbie here, I'm currently learning about asynchronous execution in Dart. I'm a bit irritated about how concurrency works in Dart, take the following scenario from their codelab:

```
void printOrderMessage () async {
  try {
    var order = await fetchUserOrder();
    print('Awaiting user order...');
    print(order);
  } catch (err) {
    print('Caught error: $err');
  }
}

Future<String> fetchUserOrder() {
  // Imagine that this function is more complex.
  var str = Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () => throw 'Cannot locate user order');
  return str;
}

Future<void> main() async {
  await printOrderMessage();
}
```

In this case, the asynchronous operation is fetching the the user order from say a DB. Now because of Dart's await / async mechanism, every function that is related to the async operation is required to have a `Future<>` return type and must be tagged with `async`.

This feels clunky ... Imagine if some value deep in my function chain is being calculated asynchronously, would I really need to always return a future? Is there some other construct to synchronize code in Dart than await? Or have I misunderstood the concept?

Comment: Anything that calls an asynchronous function is inherently asynchronous. That's how it works in Dart, Javascript (ES6), Typescript, and Python 3.5+. (A function doesn't have to be _declared_ `async` though, if it does not use the corresponding `await` syntax sugar)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If callers need to be able to *wait* for your asynchronous operation to finish, then your asynchronous function must return a `Future` that can be `await`ed.  This is contagious; if callers of those callers need to be able to wait, then they too need to have `Future`s to wait upon.

If callers should *not* wait, then you can have a "fire-and-forget" function that does not need to return a `Future`:

```dart
Future<void> foo() {
  // ...
}

// Does not need to return a Future.  Consequently, callers cannot
// directly determine when `foo` completes.
void bar() {
  foo();
}
```

Comment: What I don't understand is why the calling function also has to be async? Why not just block the main thread while waiting?

Comment: And what actually happens when I execute an aysnc function? Does it spawn a new thread?

Comment: @Wecherowski Dart is single-threaded (but does allow parallel execution via *isolate*, which are more akin to separate processes).  The whole point of an asynchronous function is to avoid blocking.  Asynchronous functions defer execution to the Dart event loop.  Also read https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a

Comment: ok, got it. Was a bit confused with the actual purpose of await (coming from the Java world).